# Missing required parameter for file download route

Tags: php, laravel

Route:

```
 Route::get('download/{mixtape_file}', 'MixtapeController@download')-
    >name('download');
```

View download button:

```
 <a href="{{ route('download', $mixtape->mixtape_file) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
 </a>
```

Controller download function:

```
 public function download($mixtape_file)
 {
    $mixtape = Mixtape::where('mixtape_file', '=', $mixtape_file)-
    >firstOrFail();
    $file = public_path('audio/' . $mixtape->mixtape_file);

    return response()->download($file);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route)

> If the route accepts parameters, you may pass them as the second
>   argument to the method:

```
$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);
```

so in your case it would be

```
<a href="{{ route('download', ['mixtape_file'=> $mixtape->mixtape_file]) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `pass` your data through `array` as a `second` parameter in `route()` helper method.

```
<a href="{{ route('download', ['mixtape_file'=> $mixtape->mixtape_file]) }}">
```